# wget is returning an html page instead of original file

Tags: io-redirection, wget, http

In my case the problem is with SourceForge.net. Actually I was trying to download these files:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.4.0/wxPython-src-2.9.4.0.tar.bz2/download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.4.0/wxPython-docs-2.9.4.0.tar.bz2/download
```

Something did not went good, so I logged **wget**, and the log file was:

```
--2012-08-21 09:52:17--  http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.4.0/wxPython-src-2.9.4.0.tar.bz2/download
Resolving sourceforge.net... 216.34.181.60
Connecting to sourceforge.net|216.34.181.60|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 18846 (18K) [text/html]
Saving to: `download'

     0K .......... ........                                   100% 6.30K=2.9s

2012-08-21 09:52:25 (6.30 KB/s) - `download' saved [18846/18846]

--2012-08-21 09:52:25--  http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.4.0/wxPython-docs-2.9.4.0.tar.bz2/download
Connecting to sourceforge.net|216.34.181.60|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

FINISHED --2012-08-21 09:52:28--
Downloaded: 1 files, 18K in 2.9s (6.30 KB/s)
```

*As you can see in this log file, I end up in getting a single HTML file :(*

---

This shows that wget doesn't waits on the page to let webpage to redirect it to another location, and it downloads the page itself.

#### Question:

I want those two files, with wget, how can I?

Answer (score 5):

It seems redirection is disabled at your wget, try specifying `--max-redirect=2` or a higher number. You probably also want to specify `--trust-server-names` to allow wget to update the file name after redirection, otherwise the downloaded files will still be called *download*.

Comment: I set those two options, but still getting an HTML file.

Comment: @Santosh Interesting, it works here. Which wget version do you use?

Comment: GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.

Comment: Do you find any error in [my .wgetrc file](https://gist.github.com/3412725)?

Comment: @Santosh No, but have you tried it without?

Comment: Hey, It is working! But I don't like passing those much argument everytime I download anything. What is wrong with my wget?

Comment: I'm quite sure something is wrong with my .wgetrc file. I need some research on it.

Comment: Try commenting out all configurations in your .wgetrc file. Then comment in one after the other and call the wget command from above. You should see which of your configurations leads to the strange behaviour.

Comment: I found that `--user-agent` was creating the problem. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your Case is redirect , But when you redirect just for your cookies, `FireFox` has two `extension`  that one export a `txt file` from your cookie with `wget` format, and second import it.
Then you use :

```
wget --load-cookies your_cookies_file.txt your_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that before downloading the website requires some cookies to be set (for example to know that you're a logged in user, or that you've accepted the license agreement, etc). So, your download should work fine when done from the browser but would fail with wget.

You can look up the missing cookie depending on your use case, and either use the authentication options available with wget or simply send the cookie data using the --header option.

Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: No, you don't need any cookies. Try `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.4.0/wxPython-src-2.9.4.0.tar.bz2`.

Comment: That's the solution for this particular website. I was mentioning the more common one.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -m <url>
```

was the incantation that worked for me when I had this issue. From the documentation:

```
-m
--mirror
    Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets
    infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l
    inf --no-remove-listing.
```

Answer (score 0):

How come no-one is mentioning the .netrc file? If the web site requires a login, there must be a .netrc file that holds credential information. That is what tripped me up when I had a similar problem.